# How to tell DB size with MongoID on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, mongoid, mongoid3

We're using the [MongoHQ](https://addons.heroku.com/mongohq) addon on Heroku, with the [Mongoid 3.0](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html) adapter. The addon plans come with a size limit, and Mongo will silently fail writing when the DB limit has been reached (unless configured for safe mode--in which case it'll throw exceptions).

I'm trying to query from within the app how close we are and send an alert if we've reached the limit. How can I run something like the `db.stats()` command but using Mongoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out how to do this in Mongoid 3.x which uses Moped as driver, not the Ruby driver from 10gen.

It was the author of Moped himself who answered a [github issue](https://github.com/mongoid/moped/issues/139) raised on the matter.

```
Mongoid.default_session.command(collstats: 'collection_name')
```

This will return the same results as `db.stats()` from the Mongo console. As an additional bonus, if the collection is capped, there'll be a flag in the return values indicating that.

Comment: `Mongoid.default_session` is now deprecated, but the command above is still valid: just use `Mongoid.default_client.command(collstats: 'collection_name')`

Answer (score 0):

You can call the ".db" method on your object (e.g. a Document), and do .stats on it.

For example:

```
MyBlog.db.stats
```

For verisons prior to Mongoid 3.0.0, `Mongoid.master.stats` should also work.

Comment: By object you mean a class that has `include Mongoid::Document`? One of my Mongoid classes is called `Metric`. Using your suggestion, I tried `Metric.db.stats`, and I get `undefined method 'db' for Metric:Class`. I also tried with an instance--same problem. Same with trying `Mongoid.default_session`. It seems there is no `db` method. I'm using Mongoid 3.0.10.